# How to react on collision detection in 2d platformers

Tags: collision-detection, game-engine

i wrote an html5 gaming framework and tried to create an 2d platformer. But i stuck on the collision detection part of the game, my framework contains an rect object with the method "intersects". So you can check if the rect intersects with another rect, it works fine but i have no idea how to react on this method. I've tried to set the player position to the last "non colliding" position but the problem with that was the player speed offset, every time there was a gap with the with of the player speed...

I can't think any further myself.

Comment: I think this is a game design question in general and not specifically related to HTML5 or JS. You should update your question's tags.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give you a detailed answer soon.

Comment: No clue but don't update players position when it's colliding?

Comment: @ManyQuestions sry i dont really understand what u are trying to tell me :/. 

Every game tick it checks if the player is colliding with another rect, if yes set the player pos to the old pos. But there is an offset equal to the player speed.

Comment: Can you explain more about the player speed offset in your question?

Comment: @ManyQuestions every game tick this happens: player.x += player.vel.x (player.vel.x is 5 by pressing d and -5 by pressing a) So the player is on the x position 10 and is moving to the right (player.vel.x = 5) and the rect is on position x = 14. One tick later the player have the x position 15 and the game sad STOOOP u are colliding with another rect so go to your old position, so the player moves back to x = 10. I think you see the problem, right? There are 3 pixels between the position that is not colliding (x=10) and the colliding position (x=14) because the player moves in 5px steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a game mechanics question in general, not only for HTML5/JS games.
I'm not familiar with HTML5 syntax, so you might have to rewrite some details of my code examples. Also, I don't know how exactly you structured your code; I'll assume that both the player and the block have some functions like `getX()`, `getXSpeed()`, `setX()` and so on.

When you detect collision between the player (or any other object that can move) and an environment block you'll want to update the player's position so it just touches the block without intercepting it. Before you can do this, you'll want to find out *how* it collides with the block: Did the player enter the block from above, from the left, from the right or from the bottom side?

First, we need the player's position.

```
playerX = player.getX();
playerY = player.getY();
```

Depending on the direction in which the player is moving, you'll want to add the player's width and height to get the coordinates of the corner that points in the direction in which the player is moving.

```
if(player.getXSpeed() > 0) {
    playerX += player.getWidth();
}
if(player.getYSpeed() > 0) {
    playerY += player.getHeight();
}
```

Next, you'll want to get the block's sides that are closest to the player's previous position. You can check whether the player's speed is positive or negative to find out from which side he's coming. Together, they represent the coordinates of the corner that points in the direction from which the player is coming.

```
blockX = player.getXSpeed() > 0? block.getX() : block.getX() + block.getWidth();
blockY = player.getYSpeed() > 0? block.getY() : block.getY() + block.getHeight();
```

Now we have the Y coordinate of the vertical side and the X coordinate of the horizontal side of the block that the player passed through, and in total we have the coordinates of the corner between both sides.

I created a small diagram in case you don't understand why we are doing this:

[image: Collision Diagram]

The black box represents the environment block. The orange frames represent the player's previous and current positions. The blue line represents the path the player has moved. We now need to check whether the blue dot, which represents the block's corner, is above or below that line. This tells us whether or not the player bumped against the horizontal or the vertical side of the block.

If the player hits the vertical side, the inclination of the blue line will be smaller than the inclination from the player's corner to the block's corner. In terms of maths this means:

```
(currentPlayerY - previousPlayerY) / (currentPlayerX - previousPlayerX)
```

is smaller than

```
(currentPlayerY - blockY) / (currentPlayerX - blockX)
```

If this does not apply, the player hits the horizontal side of the block.
Your code will look somewhat like this:

```
bool verticalSide = abs(player.getYSpeed() / player.getXSpeed()) < abs((playerY / blockY) / (playerX - blockX));
```

Since we can disregard gravity, we can pretend that the player's movement is linear. We only need one point on this line to tell which direction the player is coming from. This means that `(currentPlayerY - previousPlayerY) / (currentPlayerX - previousPlayerX)` will always be equal to `player.getYSpeed() / player.getXSpeed()`, no matter how far away the player has been in the previous game cycle.
Note that the player does not necessarily come from the top left, so the inclination we calculated could be negative. We use the math class' `abs()` function that programming languages usually provide to get the absolute value, i.e. turn all negative values positive.

Now that we know whether we are dealing with horizontal or vertical collision, we can update the player's position accordingly:

```
if(verticalSide) {
    player.setX(player.getXSpeed() > 0? blockX - player.getWidth(): blockX);
    player.setXSpeed(0);
} else {
    player.setY(player.getYSpeed() > 0? blockY - player.getHeight(): blockY);
    player.setYSpeed(0);
}
```

If `verticalSide` is true, the player is bumping against the side of the block. Now we check whether or not the player's x speed is positive to find out whether he comes from the left or from the right and update his position so he just touches the block. We also set his horizontal speed to 0. However, if `verticalSide` is not true, the player is bumping against the top or the bottom of the block, so we do the same thing for the y axis. This should be everything you need.

But I have an additional tip for you: You most likely need information whether or not the player is currently touching the ground to determine whether he can jump when the space bar or whatever key is pressed. To do this, you should create a boolean field `grounded` in your player class that is set to false every time the player is moved. During collision checking, set it to true again if the player is hitting the top of a block, i.e. `verticalSide` is `false` and `player.getYSpeed() > 0` is `true`. If the jump key is pressed, check whether `grounded` is `true` before triggering a jump.

The funny thing is that I had exactly the same problem just yesterday and I figured out this solution, but compressed it to only a few lines of code, so I had to work backwards to remember what exactly I did here. Guess I should comment my code in the future.

Comment: Oh my god, thx sooooo much man :)). Since i started to create games with javascript/java etc. i had this problem and never solve it. I just find solutions for collision detection but not how to react on that. You made my day resp. my holidays.

Regards from germany. And a happy new year (when the time comes) :) again thx sooo much.

Comment: No problem and also einen guten Rutsch back from the German city Ratingen near Düsseldorf.

Comment: Oh, ein problem hab ich noch, wenn ich jetzt als spieler von einem Block falle und ganz schnell a oder d drücke um an den block ran zu kommen teleportiert es mich noch oben/unten auf der y coordinate, weißt du woran das liegt ?

Comment: Joa, ich habe inzwischen auch Bugs entdeckt ... Ich versuche das gerade selber noch zu verbessern. Wenn ich was habe, lasse ich es dich wissen.

Comment: Hast du vielleicht Skype oder so, dass ich dich kontaktieren kann?